# Are Parse IDs deterministic?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I know that in Mongo, when you create IDs, the IDs are created in part by a time element which can be nice for sorting without using any other keys like `createdAt` or `updatedAt`. Is the same true for IDs created in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse-server doesn't use deterministic IDs for the object but 10 characters random strings (which can be configured on your side also if you wish to have longer objectIds)

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/cryptoUtils.js#L39